# Electron NodeJS spawn error when running certain commands: spawn ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, spawn

So, I'm trying to use **spawn** in my Electron application to run the `flutter --version` command.
This command works perfectly fine on my terminal.

Every solution I've seen implies I don't have it in my `process.env.PATH` variable. But when I do a `console.log( process.env.PATH );`, the path to my Flutter command is there.

Here is the current code I'm trying to execute:

```
const flutterVer = spawn('flutter', ['--version', '/c']);

flutterVer.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

Which returns:

```
Uncaught Error: spawn flutter ENOENT
    at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:464:5)
    at __node_internal_errnoException (node:internal/errors:594:12)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

I tried testing with another command, like `git --version`, and that worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Can `which flutter`  find the program? If not, it's not in your PATH.

Comment: @Ram Just tried `which flutter` in both my terminal and in spawn, the path is returned on both attempts. Which makes this error even more confusing :)

Comment: @Ram for reference, in my spawn function above `which flutter` returns `stdout: /c/Program Files/Flutter/flutter/bin/flutter`

Comment: Could it be a permission issue maybe?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Is that program built for Windows? What happens when you run it directly?

Comment: @Ram Yh I'm on Windows and it's made for Windows. All `flutter` commands run fine on my terminal.

Comment: @Ram thanks for looking into it :) . I've found a workaround and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a neat workaround by using `exec` instead of `spawn` like so.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const flutterVer = exec('flutter --version');

flutterVer.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

Will have too look into what the differences are between `exec` and `spawn`, but for now, it does what I need.